# Website Gallery

Tags: javascript, php, web

I need to create a website photo gallery. I am currently using galleriajs. The problem I can't deal with is non-standard photo sizes. Vertical images and other resolutions are stretched strangely. I would like to find a gallery that works like a slider, which has a fullscreen / lightbox option. If the image is not horizontal or has a different resolution than the default, let it just zoom in, or let the fullscreen mode fit the appropriate frame around it. Unfortunately, despite the search, I did not find anything that would solve my problem.

Im currently using: https://galleriajs.github.io/
[image]